# Interface Alias acting like Singleton when it shouldn't in TYPO3 12.4.6?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a service `MyService` that extends `MyServiceInterface`.
In the `Services.yaml` I configure:

```
My\Extension\Domain\Interface\MyServiceInterface:
  alias: My\Extension\Service\MyService
  public: true
```

When I want to use the service, I use `GeneralUtility::makeInstance(MyServiceInterface::class)`.
The `MyServiceInterface` does not extend the `SingletonInterface`, so it shouldn't be a singleton, right?

Because when I get the service with `GeneralUtility::makeInstance()`, it has the values of the last time I used it in the same call and does not create a new object as I would expect.

This problem does not occur if I skip the Interface step, so when I remove the config from the `Services.yaml` and get it with `GeneralUtility::makeInstance(MyService::class)`.

Is this an issue or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe also set "shared: false" in your Services.yaml?

Comment: @Chris I tried that already, it just throws an error: `Allowed configuration keys for service aliases are "alias", "public" and "deprecated".`

Comment: Do you set `autoconfigure: true` for the `_defaults`? That one might take care of properly adjusting the 'shared' attribute. Otherwise I'd try to setup xdebug listen on `GU::makeInstance()` and trace the steps. The v12 code really explicitly checks for SingletonInterface, but there are other possibilities also returning an existing instance if it is found in the member property cache...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `shared: false` in the `Services.yaml` file. But you can't do it on the Interface with the alias definition, but on the real class itself.

```
My\Extension\Service\MyService:
  shared: false

My\Extension\Domain\Interface\MyServiceInterface:
  alias: My\Extension\Service\MyService
  public: true
```

With that, the service is no longer shared.